# Make private property public/make readonly one writeable with Swift category?

Tags: swift, private, categories, readonly, public

[The question is the same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197579/objective-c-make-private-property-public-with-objective-c-category)

But I need a solution for Swift. If it is possible in Swift in general? Of course I mean a solution without creating Objective C file and importing it into swift code

Comment: Just make a public property in the extension whose getter/setter forwards the call to the private one. What's your issue?

Comment: @Alexander issue is that you cannot access private vars in extensions - that won't work

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski It will need to be made `fileprivate`, until this this proposal is implemented: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md

Comment: yeah I will edit my answer with some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - in Swift it's not possible - at least not in current Swift 3 version.

If the variable is defined as "private" you cannot even access it from extensions and even not by subclassing it.

If you can make this "private" variable as "fileprivate" or "internal" - it would open a possibility to expose them via public methods.

Here is a documentation on that from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

If you are working with Swift 2 - you should be able to make public function that will return private variables from main class.